# zsh and Ruby print issue

Tags: command-line, zsh, ruby, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Has anyone come across an issue where Ruby's print method leaves behind a % at the end of the line using zsh?

I'm using oh-my-zsh (https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) with iTerm2.

Here is an example of my output:

```
➜  Strings  ruby terminal-input.rb
What is your favorite movie? django
Your favorite movie is django.%
```

I've tried using my native terminal on OSX 10.9.2 and had the same issue. If I switched my shell to bash, everything worked as expected.

Any help here would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your script, as the `%` is not part of the scripts output but put there by `zsh`. `zsh` prints a `%` (usually with reversed colors) to indicate that the last output did not finish with a newline.

The reason it seems to work just fine in `bash` is, that bash just does not indicate a missing newline. It is a good idea to finish (at least the last output) with a newline (`\n`) as some shells will not recognize it and print the next prompt in the same line as your output:

```
<someprompt> ruby -e 'print "foobar"'
foobar<someprompt>
```

The ruby `print` command does not append a newline automatically:

```
% ruby -e 'print "foobar"'
foobar%
%
```

You can either just add it on your own in a number of ways

```
% ruby -e 'print "foobar\n"'
foobar
% ruby -e 'print "foobar" + "\n"'
foobar
% ruby -e 'print "foobar", "\n"'
foobar
%
```

Or you can just use `puts` instead of print

```
% ruby -e 'puts "foobar"'
foobar
%
```

Comment: You are right, _zsh prints a % (usually with reversed colors) to indicate that the last output did not finish with a newline_. But only if the _PROMPTSP_ option is set, so use `unset PROMPT_SP` to disable the finishing `%` an get bash's behavior.

Comment: @mpy This is partially right, `setopt +o PROMPT_SP` (`PROMPT_SP` is an option not a parameter) will prevent `zsh` from recognizing partial lines, but it also will lead to the partial line to be overwritten with the next prompt. It would probably be better to leave `PROMPT_SP` on and set `PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''`, which then prints an empty string rather than the default `%`.

Comment: My bad, that should read `unsetopt` in my yesterday's comment. And I also forgot to mention another option to turn off to emulate bash's behavior -- that should be correct now: `unsetopt PROMPT_SP PROMPT_CR`